# Asynchronous Problems with Javascript Hacker News API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Hacker News recently released an [API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) that I am using to display what the current top ten items are on Hacker News. I am running into some problems.

When I run the code below, the order of the items on the frontpage are inaccurate, jumping from the second one in the frontpage to the fourth, to the first, to the fifth, to the third and so on. Running the code again results in a slightly different order again.

```
$.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', function(json) {
    var convoText = '<ol>';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            $.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + json[i] + '.json', function(json2) {
                convoText += '<li><a href="' + json2.url + '">' + json2.title + '</a></li>';
                if (i === 9) {
                    convoText += '</ol>';
                    addConvo(convoText);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
});
```

I understand that this is an effect of Javascript's asynchronous nature. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQueries $.when for that:

```
  $.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', function(json) {
    var requests = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      requests.push($.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + json[i] + '.json'));
    }

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
      var results = [].slice.call(arguments);
      var list = results.map(function(arr) {
        return '<li><a href="' + arr[0].url + '">' + arr[0].title + '</a></li>';
      });
      var convoText = '<ol>' + list.join('') + '</ol>';
      console.log(convoText);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm rather new to jQuery.

Comment: added a complete sample

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

The knack is to create and append a `<li><a></a></li>` structure synchronously in the loop - thereby establishing the correct order - then populate it asynchronously with `json2` data when it arrives.

```
$.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', function(json) {
    var $ol = $('<ol/>').appendTo(...);//wherever
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(json.length, 10); i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var $a = $('<li><a></a></li>').appendTo($ol).find('a');
            $.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + json[i] + '.json', function(json2) {
                $a.attr('href', json2.url).text(json2.title);
            });
        })(i);
    }
});
```

You will have to complete the `.appendTo(...)` line. I don't know from the question where the `<ol>...</ol>` is appended.

Comment: upvoted for the only solution that doesn't wait until all the requests are complete in order to display the list items.

Comment: @DanielKopitchinski, a fellow genius, I love you!

Comment: Nobody has mentioned `Math.min(json.length, 10)` yet!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to fix this. The easiest is, instead of appending to `convoText`, use an array, and set its index when you get data. Like `data[i] = json2;`. Then when all your data is fetched, join your array.

A more structural fix would be to rearchitect your loop as a collection of promises, and construct your HTML when they have all resolved (what @xat was alluding to above).